# Unable to set credentials with Google texttoaudio API

Tags: google-text-to-speech

I was able to set to set the credentials for Google's translation but with texttospeech I'm having a lot of trouble.  First, I couldn't get the credentials as a json file, but got it as just a string. I haven't been able to find anyone else whose credentials are strings every one else has a json file.  I converted the string to a json file but I don't think that is helping because it seems that they json object has to be a dictionary. In any case when I try this:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

key1 = 'key.json'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(key1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-13-c7d030662a35>", line 1, in <module>
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(key1)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 209, in from_service_account_file
    filename, require=['client_email', 'token_uri'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/_service_account_info.py", line 73, in from_filename
    return data, from_dict(data, require=require)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/_service_account_info.py", line 46, in from_dict
    missing = keys_needed.difference(six.iterkeys(data))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 575, in iterkeys
    return iter(d.keys(**kw))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

When I try this code the following happens:

```
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'key.json'
client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-14-d30e5cd41087>", line 2, in <module>
    client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/texttospeech_v1/gapic/text_to_speech_client.py", line 159, in __init__
    address=api_endpoint, channel=channel, credentials=credentials
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/texttospeech_v1/gapic/transports/text_to_speech_grpc_transport.py", line 61, in __init__
    channel = self.create_channel(address=address, credentials=credentials)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/texttospeech_v1/gapic/transports/text_to_speech_grpc_transport.py", line 91, in create_channel
    address, credentials=credentials, scopes=cls._OAUTH_SCOPES, **kwargs
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 177, in create_channel
    credentials, _ = google.auth.default(scopes=scopes)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 305, in default
    credentials, project_id = checker()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 165, in _get_explicit_environ_credentials
    os.environ[environment_vars.CREDENTIALS])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 102, in _load_credentials_from_file
    credential_type = info.get('type')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I think this is because my json object is not a dict but a string. But the key that Google gave me was a string and not a json file, so I really don't know what to do here.  Plus their documentation is too hard to understand.

Comment: Did you create your key using the service account instructions here - https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production?

Comment: yes, I did .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you have a string, are you referring to the Key ID? You will still need the json file associated with that key.

To create a new json file, go to Google Cloud Console -> IAM & Admin -> Service Accounts. Select one of your service accounts and click "Create Key" which will download the key as a json file. It can only be downloaded once.